# error in importing Rating model from star_rating.models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use django_ratings but when i try to import it and i fail.

I tried to just include {% ratings object %} in templates after configuring settings but i got an error 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'.
Here is the settings

```
#star rating settings 
STAR_RATINGS_RERATE_SAME_DELETE = True
STAR_RATINGS_RERATE = True
STAR_RATINGS_ANONYMOUS = True
STAR_RATINGS_OBJECT_ID_PATTERN = '[a-z0-9]{32}'
```

Templates context processor

```
'django.template.context_processors.request'
```

Any help will be much appreciated

[Error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJBqv.png)

Comment: do you add `star_ratings` into `INSTALLED_APPS ` ?

Comment: Yes i had put included it but docs had limited info, so am trying to implement a custom rating and review